# How to Reload a Bootstrap Modal popup in Yii2?

Tags: javascript, jquery, yii2, bootstrap-modal

I have a Modal popup, after the user submit the data, I want to show the results on the same popup. How do I reload that modal view? Thanks.

[image: popup view]

This is the popup view:

```
<div class="site-popup">
    <h1><?= Html::encode($this->title) ?></h1>

    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-lg-5">
            <?php $form = ActiveForm::begin(['id' => 'popup-form']); ?>
                <?= $form->field($model, 'pattern')->textArea(['rows' => 1]) ?>

                <div class="form-group">
                    <?= Html::submitButton('Submit', ['class' => 'btn btn-primary', 'name' => 'popup-button']) ?>
                </div>

            <?php ActiveForm::end(); ?>
        </div>
</div>

 <?php
    echo "<pre>";
    print_r($model->data); 
 ?>
```

This is the view that calls to the above modal popup view:

```
<p>
    <?= Html::button('Search', ['value' =>Url::to('index.php?r=site/mypopup'),'class' =>'btn btn-success', 'id'=>'modalButton']) ?>
 </p>
        <?php
            Modal::begin([
            'header'=> '<h4>Search</h4>',  
            'id' => 'modal',
            'size' => 'modal-lg',
            ]);

            echo "<div id='modalContent'></div>";

            Modal::end();
       ?>
```

The js file:

```
$(function(){
    //get the click of the search button
    $('#modalButton').click(function(){
        $('#modal').modal('show')
            .find('#modalContent')
            .load($(this).attr('value'));
        }); 
});
```

Controller:

```
public function actionPopup()
{

 $model = new PopupForm();

   if ($model->load(Yii::$app->request->post()) && $model->validate()) 
   {
      $model->insertPopup();
         return $this->renderAjax('mypopup', ['model' => $model]);

            } else {
                return $this->renderAjax('mypopup', [
                    'model' => $model,
                ]);
            } 
}
```

Comment: use just button instead of submit and then call ajax of onclick, and return the view in same modal.

Comment: What do you mean with: " return the view in same modal". Thanks @Rajesh Pradhan

Comment: i mean call ajax if save then, then return response in modal

Answer (score 2):

have you tried to wrap block with **Pjax**?

Yii2 will handle form submit, and display results from controller in modal popup.

```
<div class="site-popup">
    <h1><?= Html::encode($this->title) ?></h1>

    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-lg-5">
            <?php Pjax::begin(['enablePushState' => false]); ?>
                <?php $form = ActiveForm::begin(['id' => 'popup-form']); ?>
                <?= $form->field($model, 'pattern')->textArea(['rows' => 1]) ?>

                <div class="form-group">
                    <?= Html::submitButton('Submit', ['class' => 'btn btn-primary', 'name' => 'popup-button']) ?>
                </div>

                <?php ActiveForm::end(); ?>
            <?php Pjax::end(); ?>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: I have tried the above (wrap the whole ActiveForm with Pjax), but the popup view is not reloading after the data is submitted. What else need to be done? Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

You are using the click event on the button. Instead of click event in js you would need to call submit event like this.

```
$(function(){

    //get the click of the search button
    $('.site-popup form').submit(function(){
        $('#modal').modal('show')
            .find('#modalContent')
            .load($(this).attr('value'));
        }); 
       return false
});
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer @Ramesh Mahajan, but the popup view is not appearing with the above code :(   What could be wrong on the js file? Thanks.